# Obj-C, 'NSRangeException', reason: ' -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, analyzer

I posted a question the other day, but I didn't included enough code and I'm having a further problem. I'm not sure if I should be using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]`, but since the fix I was advise to make the other day the array doesn't have the correct amount of values.

Can someone advise / show me where I'm going wrong and if its correct to use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]` ?

```
- (void) addDoneToKeyboard {

    doneButton.hidden =  NO;

    //Add a button to the top, above all windows
    NSArray *allWindows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
    NSUInteger topWindowIndex = [allWindows count];// fix - 1;
    UIWindow *topWindow = [allWindows objectAtIndex:topWindowIndex]; //SIGABRT
```

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: ' -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'**

```
    // check if top window is of keypad or else
    NSString *topViewClassName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", 
             [topWindow class]];
    while (![topViewClassName isEqualToString:@"UITextEffectsWindow"] ) {
        --topWindowIndex;

        if(topWindowIndex < 1) // fix 0
            break;

        topWindow = [allWindows objectAtIndex:topWindowIndex];
        topViewClassName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [topWindow class]];
    }
```

//

```
    if(topWindowIndex < 1) { // fix 0
        topWindowIndex = [allWindows count] - 1;
        topWindow = [allWindows objectAtIndex:topWindowIndex];
    }

    if (doneButton.superview)
        [doneButton removeFromSuperview];

    [topWindow addSubview:doneButton];

    if (!doneButtonShownRecently) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:SLIDE_IN_ANIMATION_DURATION];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 480-53, 
                         doneButton.frame.size.width, 53);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    } else {
        doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 427, 
                         doneButton.frame.size.width, 53);
    }

    doneButtonShown = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code comments here appear to already tell you what you need to do:

```
NSUInteger topWindowIndex = [allWindows count] - 1;  
UIWindow *topWindow = [allWindows objectAtIndex:topWindowIndex];
```

Counting starts with 1, while array indexes start at 0—your two array index values are 0 (for your first window) and 1 (for your second window) but you were trying to access index value 2.

*Edit:* Note the following code is now completely redundant in the above:

```
if(topWindowIndex < 1) { // fix 0
topWindowIndex = [allWindows count] - 1;
topWindow = [allWindows objectAtIndex:topWindowIndex];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I do that I get a warning `warning: Semantic Issue: Comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false`  on `if (topWindowIndex < 0)`

Comment: topWindowIndex is an NSUInteger, an *unsigned* integer, so therefore, you cannot compare it to smaller than 0 (negative) because it simply can't become negative.

Comment: You've defined topWindowIndex as an unsigned integer, which means it can never be less than 0, and that's right because you'll never have a window at index -1 or -2. So the warning is not a problem—the question is what are you trying to achieve with the code that is looking for such an index value? Note also that code doesn't appear above.

Comment: He's not saying you should change it back to `< 0`, he's saying you should delete that entire block of code, because it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

This code you have here is also wrong:

```
// check if top window is of keypad or else
NSString *topViewClassName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", 
         [topWindow class]];
while (![topViewClassName isEqualToString:@"UITextEffectsWindow"] ) {
    --topWindowIndex;

    if(topWindowIndex < 1) // fix 0
        break;

    topWindow = [allWindows objectAtIndex:topWindowIndex];
    topViewClassName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [topWindow class]];
}
```

What you really want is:

```
// check if top window is of keypad or else
BOOL foundTextEffectsWindow = NO;
while (topWindowIndex >= 0) {
    topWindow = [allWindows objectAtIndex:topWindowIndex];
    if ([topWindow isKindOfClass:[UITextEffectsWindow class]]) {
      foundTextEffectsWindow = YES;
      break;
    }

    topWindowIndex--;
}
if (foundTextEffectsWindow) {
   // do stuff with the window
}
```